# Mockito doReturn doesn't return mocked Interface in MVC with singleton

Tags: java, mockito

I have **A.class** to test:

```
private void register(...) {
    
                ...
        
                abcInterface abc = ControllerFactory.getABCController().getABCInterface(); //returns real interface instead of mock
        
                Call<SOMECLASS> call = abc.subscribe(...);

                Response<SOMECLASS> response = call.execute();

                ...
            }
```

**ControllerFactory.class** is a class where single instance of `AbcController` is instantiated.

I have to mock `abcInterface` to mock then request and response, and I wrote the following:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
public class ATest {
    
    @Mock
    AbcInterface AbcInterface;
    
    @Mock
    Call<SOMECLASS> request;
    
    @Mock
    ControllerFactory controllerFactory;
    
    @Mock
    AbcController abcControllerMock;
    
    @Before
    public void setup() {
         
        ControllerFactory.createAbcController(); //always single instance is instantiated
    }

    @Test
    public void registerTest() {
         Mockito.doReturn(dmsControllerMock).when(controllerFactory).getDmsController();
      
   Mockito.doReturn(abcInterface).when(abcControllerMock).getAbcInterface();
        
        SOMECLASS response = ...

        Response<SOMECLASS> response = Response.success(200, response);

       Mockito.doReturn(request).when(abcInterface).subscribe(Mockito.any());
        
        Mockito.when(request.execute()).thenReturn(response);
        
        A a = new A(...);
        a.register(...);
    }
}
```

The problem is that `ControllerFactory.getABCController().getABCInterface();` returns real interface instead of mock.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to mock the `getABCController` method, which should return your `abcControllerMock`, but instead `getABCController` returns an "real" instance of `AbcController` which will then return a "real" instance of `AbcInterface`.

So either mock `getABCController` or create a constructor for `A` that accepts a AbcController and then pass in your mock into that constructor when creating the instance of `A`.

Comment: I added Mockito.doReturn(dmsControllerMock).when(controllerFactory).getDmsController(); but it throws UnfinishedStubbingException on Mockito.doReturn(dmsInterface).when(dmsControllerMock).getDmsInterface();